# How to delete a column with a reserved word as the column name?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-bigquery-storage-api

I'm new at Big Query and I created a column that has a reserved word in one of the tables:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNneM.png)

Now that I'm trying to remove it by rewriting the table with a new query, I always get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaDVG.png)

The syntax i'm using is this:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(upsert, delete upsert) FROM 'table' LIMIT 1000
```

Yes, I created two columns with the names upsert and delete upsert. I couldn't find a way to rename the 'delete upsert' one to, at least 'delete_upsert', and I'm in a pickle, 'cause I don't want to create a new table because of that and lose historical data.

any thoughts that may help me?
Thanks in advance! :)

- I was able to remove the column 'upsert' using EXCEPT in a query, but not 'delete upsert' because it has a reserved word
- My expectation is to remove these two columns completely from the table

Comment: Does adding backticks around the column name with the space help?

Comment: Hi! I tried that and I didn't work, I might have used the wrong type of ticks, though...
I ended up selecting all the fields I wanted, saved in another table and deleted the original one, with the fields I wanted to delete. Not very efficient, but it did work ahah
Thanks for the comment! :)

Answer (score 0):

Quote them as with backticks. For example:

```sql
select `upsert` from t;
```

See [Lexical structure and syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I ended up selecting all of the fields I wanted and saving the results in a new table... less efficient, but worked just fine haha Thanks!